# Facebook Access Token Lifetime Issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to setup an FB app that posts to a single specific page whenever someone in our CMS puts up a specific post. I am not looking to enable facebook unified login etc with out CMS. We have a fishing application and we simply want to post on a specific page whenever someone checks in a fish in our CMS app which is written in PHP.

The problem I have is I need our CMS to be able to push the content to the Facebook page without user intervention, login, etc. So far everything works fine, except for the expiry of the 60 day access tokens.

I am guessing there is no way going forward to have an 'eternal' token. SO what is the set of things I need to code up to enable our php CMS to perpetually post content on our Facebook page?

Only our Facebook account with the single page needs access to the app.

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, but I have been googling high and low for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot find the solution you want is because it doesn't exist.  The exteneded access token will expire after 60 days.  Your page admin user must come back to your application periodically to refresh their login (which you will then take that short access token and "exchange" it for a 60 day one).  This is the ONLY way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

so, this in theory should work:

1. Introduce some error handling that catches when the token expires.
2. Write a server side function/module that posts a login to facebook for you and retrieves what you need automatically. There are plugins that can do this (by this i mean emulate a browser) for you via php (see links). Or just build your own script in perl/python with mechanize(or other command line browser) that pulls the information for you and writes it back to the php file etc.
3. Call the perl script/python module/php class/function from your server side code.

@DMCS if you can think of it, you can do it ;)

sorry if this seems complicated, DMCS is correct, normally you have to do it by hand, but in theory you can always script it, i guess is my point.

option 2: create said perl/python script described above and run in cron job every 59 days or what have you. :)

http://www.lastcraft.com/browser_documentation.php -- php "mechanize" like module

http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/ -- another php "mechanize" like module

http://bit.ly/L3PRgR -- mechanize perl :)

http://bit.ly/L3PZgc -- mechanize python :)